# Counting and storing the number of checkboxes in a sharepoint list

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

I have a SharePoint list that's purpose is to measure the competency of my team.
I have a highly regulated financial environment and there are over 790 "core competencies" to maintain for over 200 colleagues.

I've decided to use SP 2013 as the solution. The list contains fields like "Credit Cards" which are "multi choice check box fields"
Inside Credit Cards - There are more than 30 checkboxes (eg. opening a credit card , closing a credit card, refunding a fee, etc)

Essentially, when users select boxes (basically saying "I know how to do this") , I'd like the number of checkboxes in that field to counted and placed in another SP field. 
For example, the checkbox field is called "Credit Cards"
Then there is another field called CreditCardScore which counts the number of boxes ticked in the credit card score and ALSO the total number and displays as a %. (We can split this up into multiple fields, but it needs to update every time the form is opened)

So if a user ticked 15 out of 30 boxes, essentially I'd like to know they're only 50% competent at their job. (So I can focus on getting them trained up)

I'd like to use jQuery to do this as I've seen numerous examples of counting boxes, but I'm not sure about the storing it in another field part. Any help would be appreciated and sorry if this is the wrong forum

Comment: Maybe survey list could do a trick?

Comment: Nah it doesn't , because the survey will need to be updated continuously and won't update previous responses

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow that starts each time an item is created or modified. Set a variable for the number of checkboxes check and set it to 0, then check each checkbox, if it's checked, add 1 to the variable. After checking all checkboxes, set your CreditCardScore to the value of the variable (or to the variable/30*100 to get the percentage). Make the field read-only. I hope that will help!

Comment: Hi Kate. I have created approval workflows in the past, but have no idea on how I can create a workflow to "check each checkbox" . Can you elaborate. I'd appreciate any help I can get. I have spent quite a bit of time looking for for how to do what you've suggested but am unable to find a resource, I know this might be trivial so apologies in advance